# Question about reading from a text with a spacing between lines

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to write a program which reads long lines of data byte by byte in a hex format. I am able to read the data in hex format byte by byte as intended however it comes with two problems.

1) A small problem I face is for example: if the text code being read is `AA BB CC-` (take - as an extra character space) it would cause the code to stop reading the rest of the line after the character space.

2) The next problem is that if there is an extra line of space in between lines. Example:

```
AA BB  
--(paragraph or line spacing in between here)  
CC DD
```

The program would stop reading after AA BB. Do you have any ideas on how to remedy it?

For problem (1) I added another `read(inline, v_SPACE1);` line after the clock cycle. Which seems to work for the most part. Except the transcript keeps showing TEXTIO procedure READ(CHARACTER) : Parameter L designates an empty string. I hope it doesn't affect future readings.

For problem (2) I tried adding readline(infile, inline);  and another while loop but I guess that wouldn't work.

```
--Library used
----
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE IEEE.std_logic_textio.all;
LIBRARY STD;
USE STD.textio.all;
USE IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;
USE IEEE.numeric_std.all;
---
--signal used
signal readdatainput : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);


--variable used
variable v_SPACE1     : character;
variable inline    : line; --line number declaration
file   listfile    : text is in  "list.txt"; --this file is used for a different purpose 
variable inputdata : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
file      infile : text;
variable inputdata : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
------------------------------------
begin
-
-
-
file_open(infile,inline.ALL,READ_MODE); --inline.ALL refers an earlier part of the program which reads from a text files and gathers the names of files to open
while not endfile(infile) loop   --checking the "END OF FILE" is not reached.
    readline(infile, inline);       --reading a line from the file.
    next when inline(1) = '#'; 
    next when inline(1) = '[';
    while (inline'length /= 0)  loop 
        hread(inline, inputdata);
        readdatainput <= inputdata;
        wait until rising_edge(clock);

        read(inline, v_SPACE1); -- this is my attempt for character space   
    end loop;
end loop;
file_close(infile);
```

With this code, it would read byte by byte however stops reading once it reaches a line/paragraph space in between lines.

Comment: You have some issues in the code that prevent full understanding. 
You appear to be re-using `inline` for the filename and the lines from the file. Without calling DEALLOCATE on `inline` before the loop you are creating a memory leak.You also dont show what libraries you are using or the declaration of `v_SPACE1`. Please update the question to be a fully reporducable example.

Comment: The inline.all for filename refers to an earlier part of the program in which the names of the text files is read which is then open here. I added the libraries and variables used

Comment: There are still declarations missing. What is infile? readdatainput? hread should drop whitespace between reads, so the attempt to read in a space shouldnt be needed. If this is not the case for the non-standard std_logic_textio library, then I recommend using VHDL 2008 as hread is part of std_logic_1164. Also, I recommend using '93 syntax for file declarations rather than '87.

Comment: I am using USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all; for hread. Is that the incorrect library? Also, what happens if there is 2 whitespace inbetween reads?

Comment: if you are using VHDL 2008, you can delete std_logic_textio package.  read/oread/hread will remove ALL whitespace between reads.

Comment: Also see [How to Eliminate whitespaces while Reading a file in VHDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42580828/how-to-eliminate-whitespaces-while-reading-a-file-in-vhdl) which only uses `read`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the issue(s) can be remedied.

From your question it appears your code is missing the ability to skip trailing white space or blank lines. hread/read etc. already has the ability to skip leading white space.

The code snippet is expanded to a VHDL design unit capable of simulating and changes are made to ignore empty lines and trailing white space:

```vhdl
library ieee;
use std.textio.all;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_textio.all;

entity reporducable is
    generic ( filename: string := "data.txt");
end entity;

architecture example of reporducable is
    signal clock:           std_logic := '0';
    signal readdatainput:   std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
begin
some_process:
    process
        variable inline: line;
        file infile: text;
        variable inputdata: std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
        variable c: character;
    begin
        file_open(infile,filename,READ_MODE);
        while not endfile(infile) loop   
            readline(infile, inline);
            next when inline'length = 0; -- skip empty line
            next when inline(1) = '#'; 
            next when inline(1) = '[';
            while inline.all'length /= 0  loop
                while inline.all'length /= 0 loop  -- eat white space
                    c := inline(inline'left); -- read can modify or deallocate
                    if c = ' ' or c = CR or c = HT then
                        read(inline, c);
                    else
                        exit;
                    end if;
                end loop;
                if inline.all'length = 0 then  -- nothing but eaten white space
                    exit;
                end if;
                hread (inline, inputdata);
                readdatainput <= inputdata;
                wait until rising_edge(clock);  
            end loop;
        end loop;
        file_close(infile); 
        wait; 
    end process;
clock_process:
    process
    begin
        wait for 10 ns;
        clock <= not clock;
        if now > 200 ns then
            report "et fini";
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

(The entity name `reporducable` makes light of Tricky misspelling 'reproducible' in a comment.)

For data.txt:

```
# First column
AA BB CC 
DD EE FF 

77 88 99
[ignored]
```

which doesn't show trailing white space:

```
od -a data.txt
0000000    #  sp   F   i   r   s   t  sp   c   o   l   u   m   n  nl   A
0000020    A  sp   B   B  sp   C   C  sp  nl   D   D  sp   E   E  sp   F
0000040    F  nl  nl   7   7  sp   8   8  sp   9   9  nl   [   i   g   n
0000060    o   r   e   d   ]  nl
0000066
```

where the first character of a read line is either # or [, or the read line is empty or trailing white space is ignored:

[image: reporducable.jpg]

**An explanation of the use of `inline(inline'left)`**

See IEEE Std 1076-2008 16.4 Package TEXTIO:

> Each READ, SREAD, OREAD, and HREAD procedure declared in package TEXTIO extracts data from the beginning of the string value designated by parameter L and modifies the value so that it designates the remaining portion of the line on exit. Each procedure may modify the value of the object designated by the parameter L at the start of the call or may deallocate the object.

`read` operations may either use allocation of a new object, copy and deallocation of the previous object or manipulate the left bound of the object which is much faster.

Depending on which method is used to update the Line value is during a `read` an index value of 1 may be out of bounds and the 'LEFT attribute can always be used to examine the first value of the object after a `read` to insure portability.

It's safe to use an index of 1 follow a `readline` call with no intervening `read` call, `readline` is required to use allocation and  The `read` implementation choice allows performance optimization where host system allocation and deallocation may be inefficient when trimming off leading characters.